# Android - Inflate a view and draw to canvas?

Tags: android

I have a problem that would be easily solved if I could somehow inflate a view (this part is doable) but instead of letting android's UI framework handle it, I would like to be able to explicitly draw it to a Canvas object. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to draw directly on the canvas, you'll have to extend the View to create your custom component. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I should have searched the APIs before asking. Any idea how such "free" views will behave when it comes to UI events?

Comment: @zienkikk I guess I do not understand this new question. You will be able to attach the same listeners as in any other View (click, long click, key, focus, etc). You can also decide to extend Button or EditText if you need so.